# Drawing rotated semicircles with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

What is the easiest way to draw this figure with tikz (using written code)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\SSide{2}

\begin{document}

\tikz\draw (0,0) arc(0:-180:{0.5*\SSide*sqrt(3)}) arc(270:90:0.5*\SSide) arc(150:-30:\SSide) -- (-{\SSide*sqrt(3)},\SSide) -- (-{\SSide*sqrt(3)},0) --cycle;

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another short option; now you can use a command allowing you to specify the length of a cathetus and the angle between this cathetus and the hypotenuse:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\CircTrian[2]{%
\def\SSide{#1}%
\def\Angle{#2}%
\tikz \draw (0,0) arc(0:-180:0.5*\SSide) arc(270:90:{0.5*\SSide*tan((\Angle))})  arc(180-\Angle:-\Angle:{0.5*\SSide/cos(\Angle)}) -- (-\SSide,0) -- (-\SSide,{\SSide*tan((\Angle))}) -- cycle;%
}

\begin{document}

\CircTrian{2}{30}\qquad
\CircTrian{3}{37.5}\qquad
\CircTrian{2.5}{45}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A short solution with `pst-eucl`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, pdf, x11names, border =3pt]{standalone}%

\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2cm}%
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.6,-2.1)(5,4.1)
    \pnodes(0,0){O}(0,3){A}(4,0){B}
    \pstCircleAB[linecolor=Gold2]{A}{O}%
    \pstCircleAB[linecolor=IndianRed2]{B}{O}%
    \pstMiddleAB {A}{B}{I}
    \psset{fillstyle=solid}
    \pstArcnOAB[linecolor =DarkOliveGreen3]{I}{A}{B}%
    \pspolygon(O)(A)(B)
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[semic/.style args={#1,#2}{semicircle,minimum width=#1,draw,anchor=arc end,rotate=#2},outer sep=0pt,line width=.7pt]  
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ATAN}{atan{-.75}} 
\node [semic={3cm,90}]    at (0,0){};
\node [semic={4cm,180}]   at (4,0){};
\node [semic={5cm,\ATAN}] at (0,3){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

TikZ has a ready-made shape named `semicircle`, which can be obtained by loading the `shapes.geometric` library. For the well-known (3,4,5) right triangle, we can easily specify the widths as (3cm,4cm,5cm).

We set the `arc end` (the left-most point on the diameter) as the anchor point and place that point at the required positions (vertices) with the appropriate rotation.

The command `\pgfmathsetmacro{\ATAN}{atan{-.75}}` will calculate the slope of the hypotenuse and store it in `\ATAN`. This requires the `calc` library.

Answer (score 1):

Another PSTricks solution but using lower commands.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-2)(4.5,4.5)
    \pscustom
    {
        \psarcn(0,1.5){1.5}{-90}{90}
        \gsave
        \translate(2,1.5)
        \rotate{!3 4 atan neg}      
        \psarc(0,0){2.5}{0}{180}
        \stroke
        \grestore
        \psarc(2,0){2}{180}{0}
        \closepath
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]